# VK api и python3.5 - повторная отправка сообщений

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть код для бота паблика на питоне:

```
from flask import Flask, request, json
from settings import token, confirmation_token
import messageHandler

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if 'type' not in data.keys():
        return 'not vk'
    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token
    elif data['type'] == 'message_new':
        messageHandler.create_answer(data['object'], token)
        return 'ok'
```

Код должен отвечать на сообщения, с чем он справляется.
Но, как я понимаю, когда блок `data['type'] == 'message_new'` срабатывает, после вызова функции идёт `return 'ok'`, и после повторной отправки сообщения возникать не должно. Однако она возникает.
Я впервые работаю с api, так что допучкаю, что где то сглупил, но не понимаю где.

На скриншоте видно, какие запросы отправляет vk. Но дело в том, что никаких new message после 2:41:34 я не отправлял боту. (Не говоря уже о том, что доступ к message_typing_state вообще закрыт для бота)

Как избавиться от бесконечного потока сообщений?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
Я читал в документации про параметр random_id в методе message.send(), но не разобрался как с ним работать, буду благодарен, если кто-то поделиться опытом.

Answer (score 0):

В [`документации`](https://vk.com/dev/bots_docs_2) сказано, что нужно использовать параметр `random_id`, чтобы избежать повторной отправки сообщения одному и тому же получателю. Этот параметр действует в течение одного часа.

Или можно же делать проверку на последнее отправленное, если оно было от сообщества, то ничего не произойдет, а если от пользователя, бот продолжает функционировать. Но такой метод не очень корректный, поэтому лучше следовать документации.

Comment: Я же написал в конце вопроса, что прекрасно знаю о написаном в документации параметре random_id. А вот как им корректно воспользоваться - загадка для меня.

Comment: @МихаилКраев, просто генерируешь случайное число, и отправляешь его, на примере `PHP` можно сделать так `mt_rand(20, 99999999)`

Comment: @Lets-pay-pie Я передал параметр, только на питоне. 'random_id=random.randint(1, 99999)' Однако после этого бот вообще работать перестаёт.